# tensorflow high level api vs low level api

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

The question is simple.

Should one go for low level APIs or high level API in tensorflow in his/her own projects?

If I go for high level APIs only in my Neural Network implementation: Will I e.g. be able to apply such solutions like dropout, batch normalization, learning decay, etc.? Or is it inevitable to start using lower level APIs for such cases?

My view so far is that the tensorflow community does a great job in almost everything they do but I unfortunately cannot say the same thing for their documentation. It really takes time to clearly figure out how they thought when implementing the API. Then the question is if it is really worth the time I and many others spend to make things work? Or should we always search for solutions in the high level APIs?

It is not clear to me either where the boundary goes between high level APIs and low level APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your project **goal**, project **novelty** and **complexity**.

If goal of your specific project is to learn and explore tensorflow, then I would say go for low level API, because in future you would probably need to implement your stuff, since the primary purpose of tensorflow is research.

Otherwise If its team project or a serious project, then use whatever that suits the requirements, for example if existing high level solutions like layers etc.. are not working, then you would want to implement your own stuff.

So if you are learning tensorflow and starting out go for the high-level API and if you already have some experience then start exploring the low level tensorflow API as it is highly likely that you will need low-level tensorflow API in future.

Comment: @edn Glad to help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My intention is to use it to create own software products which will even require maintenance and possibly further development. (Not necessarily for research.) Then I believe using lower level APIs when needed is a necessity. But I find the documentation extremely unstructured and it gives the picture that they do not seem to care about it. (A concrete example is tf.saved_model API.) At the end, you make things work in one way or another but I keep seeing in forums/discussions that people are suffering from BAD documentation.

Comment: Personally I am not a fan of tensorflow documentation, even their guides. They are difficult to understand, traverse and poorly structured. The approach I take in serious projects is to use simplest stuff possible(high level API) and rely on low level API or other complex solutions when situation demands it. I would like to point out that this does not mean I don't explore tensorflow API(s), I don't use low level API  unless absolutely needed(why reinvent the wheel), but have to be prepared when situation calls for it.

Comment: We seem to have the same opinion on the structural problem in tf documentation. But even just figuring out what is available in high level APIs or not is a challenge. Good documentation is a must if they are going to claim that they are democritizing AI. Thanks again for your answer! Appreciated a lot.